# Chef workstation is unable to find knife.rb unless in "chef-repo"

Tags: chef-infra, knife

1. When I run `knife node list` while in `/home/ec2-user`
   it complains

   > "WARNING: No knife configuration file found
   >   ERROR: Your private key could not be loaded from /etc/chef/client.pem
   >   Check your configuration file and ensure that your private key is readable"
2. When I run `knife node list` while in `/home/ec2-user/chef-repo`
   it executes successfully
   `chef-repo` directory contains `.chef/knife.rb`

My `knife.rb` is located in `/home/ec2-user/chef-repo/.chef/knife.rb`

My `knife.rb` contents:

```
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                'admin'
client_key               '/home/ec2-user/chef-repo/.chef/admin.pem'
validation_client_name   'chef-validator'
validation_key           '/home/ec2-user/chef-repo/.chef/chef-validator.pem'
chef_server_url          'https://XX.XX.XX.XX:443'
syntax_check_cache_path  '/home/ec2-user/chef-repo/.chef/syntax_check_cache'
cookbook_path [ '~/chef-repo/cookbooks/cookbooks' ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a "global per-user" config, either set the KNIFE_HOME environment variable to your `.chef` directory or copy/symlink your knife.rb to
`/home/ec2-user/.chef/knife.rb`

Specification:
https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/spec/unit/workstation_config_loader_spec.rb#L51

Implementation: https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/workstation_config_loader.rb#L97-L124